# Generating random (torsion) point on elliptic curve efficiently

Tags: finite-fields, computational-complexity, elliptic-curves, cryptography, torsion-groups

I am looking for an efficient way to generate a random point on an elliptic curve over a finite field, $E(\mathbb{K})$.

I know that you can pick a random $x$, compute e.g. in Weierstrass coordinates $f=x^3+ax+b$, check if it is a quadratic residue and then solve $y^2=f$ using the [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) or [Cipolla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm) algorithm. The former roughly has a complexity of $O(\log^2_2|\mathbb{K}|)$ multiplications on $\mathbb{K}$, while the latter only conditionally runs faster. If your finite field is huge and your computational power weak, this can be a lot. Is there a way to do this faster?

Furthermore, what if I want the point to belong to a particular torsion group, e.g. let's say I want to generate a point $P$ with $[m]P=O$? Is there a shortcut for such points, or do I have to generate them, and then test?

EDIT:
In more detail, I am working with supersingular elliptic curves over finite field of characteristic $p=2^u3^v\pm1$, such that $p$ prime. It roughly holds that $2^u\approx3^v$ such that there are two very large coprime torsion groups $E[2^u]$ and $E[3^v]$. The points I want to generate are in either of these torsion groups.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: To generate a point with $[m]P=O$, it might be handy to know the order of the group.

Comment: You can select random and encode it by `Koblitz's encoding method`. In Cryptography that is a problem of mapping messages to points.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well, I am working on supersingular elliptic curves. In that case, the full torsion group $E[m]$ has order $m^2$, while the group generated by $P$ would be of order $m$. Or are you asking about the actual, numerical value of $m$?

Comment: Finding the order of $E$ plus two generators shouldn't be much harder than computing the order of a single random point ?

Comment: Torsion points are solutions to [division polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials), so maybe you can solve that instead? For any random $x$ you have $1/2$ chance of a solution $y$. This means on average only two tries. I tested that Tonelli-Shanks using Sage will complete this within tens of microseconds even if $|\mathbb K|$ is around $2^{2000}$, is that fast enough?

Comment: Meant milliseconds.

Comment: @reuns But how would you find those generators quickly?

Comment: Do you know the group structure of $E(K)$? Or, equivalently, will you be generating several such points on the same curve (when you may be able to invest time in figuring out the group structure). Is $m$ small or large in relation to $|E(K)|$? For example, if you know that $|E(K)|=dm^2$ with $d$ relatively small, then you can generate an arbitrary point $P\in E(K)$ when $[d]P$ will be in the $m$-torsion subgroup. If $\gcd(d,m)=1$ then the generated point will be uniformy distributed (given that $P$ was).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The group structure is known: $E\simeq\mathbb{Z}_{p\pm1}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p\pm1}$ with $p=\text{char}(\mathbb{K})$. Ideally it should be two points on the same curve and in the same torsion group.
Concerning $m$, in my particular case, $p=2^u3^v\pm1$ so that there are two large coprime torsion subgroups $E[2^u]$ and $E[3^v]$ of about the same size and either $m=2^u$ or $m=3^v$. Thus, roughly $m=\sqrt{p}$.

Comment: @YongHaoNg A priori, I don't know the division polynomials, but in any case I think it is easier to just pick a random $x$ and check if $x^3+ax+b$ is a quadratic residue, and if not, then just to pick another $x$. 
The Tonelli-Shanks is actually quite fast, but I was wondering if there is a quicker way, maybe directly related to elliptic curves, rather than finite field arithmetic.

Comment: @Gemeis Just a random thought and not sure if this is feasible: Maybe you can try to do iterated "point halving"? Point of order two is of the form $P_1 = (x_1,0)$, then points $P_2(x_2,y_2)$ of order $4$ can be found from solving $[2]P_2 = P_1$, and so on. Expensive at the start but after that you can use the generator to generate points faster.